# android nested RelativeLayout horizontal orientation textview overlap button

Tags: android

My layout are below and I tried putting below configuration for the EditText and EditText disappear

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/filter_button"
```

EditText should be at left side and it length need to fill till the Button which is to the left of EditText.

My layout are below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="ethervision.net.ama.DirectoryActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <!-- This nested layout contains views of its own -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/search_filter">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="All Contact" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_directory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_filter"
        android:theme="@style/ListFont"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using Android Studio 0.8.2. Please kindly help :D

Cheerio,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="ethervision.net.ama.DirectoryActivity"
  android:background="#ffffff">

  <!-- This nested layout contains views of its own -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_filter">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="All Contact" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/filter_button"
        >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_directory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_filter"
    android:theme="@style/ListFont"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you can move objects around in the designer view and it will generate code for you. See if this works.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filter_button" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```